# How to cascade deletes in a database tree

Tags: sql, sqlite

How is it possible to change this SQLite3 table so subnodes are deleted together with parentnode through cascading deletes:

```
CREATE TABLE cats (cat_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
                   cat_pid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                   cat_name VARCHAR(40)
                  )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for the database to automatically delete the parents subnodes. No code is needed if the table can be set up for cascading deletes. If this is possible with SQLite.. Someone said it could be done, but not exactly how. For the time being I delete parent and subnodes using a CTE recursive query.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

Comment: A yes or no if this is possible would be appreciated. The examples I found in the docs show references to a column in another table. I want to reference a column in the same table and it didnt work. Maybe my syntax was off or maybe it wont work. Who can tell?

Comment: Then show what you've tried.